# How can I add a block with an attribute value under the price in the category grid / list?

Tags: magento2, blocks, theme, category-products

I have an attribute I want to display on the category page.  I am able to get it to show up between the "Add To Cart" button and the wishlist icons, but I can't move it up to underneath the price.

Here is the code i'm using:

catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="attr" template="Sigma_Catalog::attr.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>

    <!--<move element="attr" destination="category.product.list.additional" />-->
  </body>
</page>
```

attr.phtml

```
<div class="product" style="float: left">
    <?php
        //

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $block->getProduct();

        $credit_hours = $product->getCustomAttribute('ce_ceu')->getValue();

        if ($credit_hours != null){
            echo '<span class="credit_hours">Credit Hours - ' . $credit_hours . '</span>';
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

I've tried using the  command but it either doesn't show my block, or it breaks the attribute loading functionality ($product is null)

Answer (score 0):

add this file in your theme :

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

add your code after

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```